# How to create and manage large CSS projects?

Tags: html, css, web

I am new to web designing. I have a habit of viewing the source code of web pages and what I see is CSS files flooded with vast and complicated CSS code.

I have learnt CSS, including CSS 3, but I often wonder how could designers create such vast CSS files? How much time does it take? Do they do all the coding by typing themselves or generate the code with the help of some program?

Comment: Welcome.  Your question is "off-topic" as per the posting rules for two possible reasons, "too broad" and "primarily opinion based".  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: These broad questions can often end up being very usefull for beginners that are new to web development.

Comment: Exactly - how are people supposed to learn about modern web design if they have no idea what to even Google or how things work? The only place to start is with a broad question. Instead of making StackOverflow a welcoming place for a new user, they got 5 down votes and their question locked.

Comment: @Bill: "*how are people supposed to learn about <subject>*" - *elsewhere*, via any means they like. This isn't a beginners, or basics, site: it's a site for 'professional and enthusiasts.

Comment: @DavidThomas - you have seen the front page right? People get help for all kinds of basic questions. Looking at your history, half of the questions you asked when you were starting out could be classified as beginners questions. If you had gotten all of those closed and down voted instead of answered - would you have stuck around?

Comment: @Bill: there's that, certainly; and I was lucky enough to get here when the criteria was different, and those answering were perhaps more tolerant. But this question remains, I think, too *open-ended* (rather than simply 'basic' or 'beginner') to be objectively answered.

Comment: @DavidThomas - but it was objectively answered. There are tool chains that modern front end developers use and this was the answer that was provided and it was helpful to the person that asked. This is a prime example why so many people have stopped answering questions - we try and help and then get told that the question wasn't good enough to deserve an answer. It's just gotten ridiculous and your first comment is everything that is wrong with the StackOverflow mod squad, you don't even know what this site is for anymore.

Comment: By the way - I think this question is excellent, so I'm sad to see the downvotes.  I do agree that it doesn't happen to fit the StackOverflow guidelines (which are there for a good reason), which unfortunately in this case has led to people downvoting the question unnecessarily.  Please note that these downvotes don't reflect the quality of the question.

Comment: If you don't know *why* you're using a preprocessor then don't! Same thing if you've no idea what CSS this tool is generating (because then it'll be bloated and prone to error). Learn 5 ways to position anything, to center horiz. and vert., clear and *clearfix* up to BFC. Then look for **methodologies** like OOCSS or BEM: that's how huge projects can manage the dozens of page templates (and people) they require. Strict separation of content and style doesn't scale so well, alas.

Comment: @Dan: I'm curious, on what basis do you consider this question "excellent"?

Comment: @DavidThomas I've worked on various projects that contained difficult to unravel layers of CSS.  I'd love to hear discussion of potentially good paradigms, or ways of thinking, about the overall issue of managing complex CSS.

Comment: @Bill-Thank you for supporting me..I didn't actually knew that this issue will arise...If i haven't follow the guidelines...Then i ll take care next time...

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: And your comment explicitly mentions why you are on the wrong site then: You want a discussion.

Comment: The [consensus on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262055) seems to have been overwhelmingly against reopening the question. Why, then, did it happen - twice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most front end developers use tools such as SASS and LESS for writing their CSS.  These tools help cut down on some of the verbosity and help structure the code.  We don't just write one huge CSS file, what you see is a result of combining and minifying many files - what is usually referred to as the build process (tools like Gulp help here). But yes, there is still a lot of typing involved.

Google SASS, LESS, and Gulp to learn more.

Comment: Do we need them in future?

Answer (score 6):

CSS code can end up being vast and complicated for a number of reasons. The stylesheet may be the easiest file to become a mess. Not all of them good. I can attempt to explain why my code often ends up unnecessarily long.

Firstly, CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) allow for new lines of code to replace old lines of code, for example, the rule in line 12:

```
body#wrapper {
    width: 1200px;
}
```

can be changed in line 4123 to:

```
body#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
}
```

without deleting the previous rule. This results in plenty of laziness as the people writing the code don't delete previous, obsolete rules.

Additionally many developers start off with a framework like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). This provides many lines of CSS code. Instead of customising the existing code and removing unused rules, most folks just leave the existing code untouched and add any customisations on to the end of the file.

Not only does it not look good, but badly optimised CSS files affect your website. Many websites and applications go to great lengths to optimise their CSS files. In order to avoid creating messy CSS, it is a good idea to use tools like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) with [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/). This is what I have been doing to try and keep my CSS files smaller. LESS allows you to use mixins and variables to give you greater control over the stylesheet and Grunt can be used to concatenate many smaller CSS files.

Comment: Thanx @nicholaschris for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use Firefox or chrome. I find the element I want to change and right click > 'inspect element' from drop down. Then I change things though the CSS list on the right side of the inspector designated for that element until I get it right. I then copy my changes and put them into my CSS file, save and then refresh the page to make sure it looks the same

Designing for all of the browsers that my visitors use can be a bitch, especially with ie. but there are ie specific CSS files that I create for those to fix the issues that browser gives me.

Many designers can code everything without looking, I can do some things without looking but, for me it is just easier to see what is happening along with my changes

Comment: There are actually much easier ways to do web development. You'll want to look up 'live reload' such as https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload used with the gulp build tool. This allows you to make a change in your code file, save, and have your website CSS automatically  refresh without even having to reload the page. It's pretty magic :)

Comment: I will definitely look at that! Thank you very much:-)

Comment: @Bill Just for future browsers, that functionality is also available in Visual Studio with Web Essentials (which every web dev using VS should already have installed). I'm not sure as to browser compatibility, but it works in Chrome and I would presume IE.

Comment: Good to know, I've never used Visual Studio for web development.

Comment: Neither have I. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Developers usually use tools to write the css codes. These are advanced programming tools which will assist the developers while writing the styles like auto-completion, intellisense,
color-picker, image-picker an so on. These tools are available for free as well as paid.

few to name are: Dreamweaver, VisualStudio, Notepad++...

You can also code in any latest browsers like chrome or firefox or even ie11.